# Bounding Boxes Not Colliding (DirectX)

Tags: c++, directx, collision-detection, collision, directx-11

I've been trying to solve this issue for a while now so I'm going to try to keep it simple. Basically when trying to make two 3D models collide, collision is never detected between their bounding boxes (they pass through each other).
The models load fine and appear on the scene, I'm also able to change their properties like scale, rotation and translation, this is fine so I don't think the issue lies with the models themselves.
Everytime I draw a model in the UpdateScene() function (this updates every frame), I also calculate their bounding box, like so:

```
testModel->Draw();
CalculateAABB(testModel->boxVertices, test, testBoundingBoxMinVertex, testBoundingBoxMaxVertex);
```

The CalculateAABB function looks like this:

```
void CalculateAABB(vector<XMFLOAT3> boundingBoxVerts, XMMATRIX& worldSpace, XMVECTOR& boundingBoxMin, XMVECTOR& boundingBoxMax)
{
    XMFLOAT3 minVertex = XMFLOAT3(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX);
    XMFLOAT3 maxVertex = XMFLOAT3(-FLT_MAX, -FLT_MAX, -FLT_MAX);

    //Loop through the 8 vertices describing the bounding box
    for (UINT i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        //Transform the bounding boxes vertices to the objects world space
        XMVECTOR Vert = XMVectorSet(boundingBoxVerts[i].x, boundingBoxVerts[i].y, boundingBoxVerts[i].z, 0.0f);
        Vert = XMVector3TransformCoord(Vert, worldSpace);

        //Get the smallest vertex 
        minVertex.x = min(minVertex.x, XMVectorGetX(Vert));    // Find smallest x value in model
        minVertex.y = min(minVertex.y, XMVectorGetY(Vert));    // Find smallest y value in model
        minVertex.z = min(minVertex.z, XMVectorGetZ(Vert));    // Find smallest z value in model

        //Get the largest vertex 
        maxVertex.x = max(maxVertex.x, XMVectorGetX(Vert));    // Find largest x value in model
        maxVertex.y = max(maxVertex.y, XMVectorGetY(Vert));    // Find largest y value in model
        maxVertex.z = max(maxVertex.z, XMVectorGetZ(Vert));    // Find largest z value in model
    }

    //Store Bounding Box's min and max vertices
    boundingBoxMin = XMVectorSet(minVertex.x, minVertex.y, minVertex.z, 0.0f);
    boundingBoxMax = XMVectorSet(maxVertex.x, maxVertex.y, maxVertex.z, 0.0f);
}
```

When I move my camera, I then call a couple of functions that check if there was collision or not, for example:

```
bool checkTestCollision()
{
    if (BoundingBoxCollision(cameraBoundingBoxMinVertex, cameraBoundingBoxMaxVertex, testBoundingBoxMinVertex, testBoundingBoxMaxVertex))
    {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is what happens in the BoundingBoxCollision() function:

```
bool BoundingBoxCollision(XMVECTOR& firstObjBoundingBoxMinVertex, XMVECTOR& firstObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex, XMVECTOR& secondObjBoundingBoxMinVertex, XMVECTOR& secondObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex)
{
    //Is obj1's max X greater than obj2's min X? If not, obj1 is to the LEFT of obj2
    if (XMVectorGetX(firstObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex) > XMVectorGetX(secondObjBoundingBoxMinVertex))

        //Is obj1's min X less than obj2's max X? If not, obj1 is to the RIGHT of obj2
        if (XMVectorGetX(firstObjBoundingBoxMinVertex) < XMVectorGetX(secondObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex))

            //Is obj1's max Y greater than obj2's min Y? If not, obj1 is UNDER obj2
            if (XMVectorGetY(firstObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex) > XMVectorGetY(secondObjBoundingBoxMinVertex))

                //Is obj1's min Y less than obj2's max Y? If not, obj1 is ABOVE obj2
                if (XMVectorGetY(firstObjBoundingBoxMinVertex) < XMVectorGetY(secondObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex))

                    //Is obj1's max Z greater than obj2's min Z? If not, obj1 is IN FRONT OF obj2
                    if (XMVectorGetZ(firstObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex) > XMVectorGetZ(secondObjBoundingBoxMinVertex))

                        //Is obj1's min Z less than obj2's max Z? If not, obj1 is BEHIND obj2
                        if (XMVectorGetZ(firstObjBoundingBoxMinVertex) < XMVectorGetZ(secondObjBoundingBoxMaxVertex))

                            //If we've made it this far, then the two bounding boxes are colliding
                            return true;

    //If the two bounding boxes are not colliding, then return false
    return false;
}
```

While debugging, I've found that it does go a few if's in when 'colliding' but always fails at the last one, which means I'm doing something wrong with the BoundingBoxMin and BoundingBoxMax vertices for the models but I'm not sure why.

Here's the models 'not colliding':

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGOxw.png)

Thank you for reading and if you can help somehow I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any unit tests for these functions? If the answer is "no" then that's the first problem you fix.

Comment: Why not just use [DirectX Collision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxcollision/ns-directxcollision-boundingbox)?